# Unit Testing protected methods using Mocks and sub classes in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, access-modifiers

I am trying to unit test a few protected methods which are in a public class.
I am inheriting from this class and testing the inherited class by returning the super class' methods from it.
My sample code is as follows:

Base Class:

```
public class A
{
    // Private variables here
    public A(){ }

    protected virtual bool MethodOfA()
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        //some operation here to set returnValue
        return returnValue;
    }

    protected bool AnotherMethodOfA()
    {
        bool anotherReturnValue = false;
        bool operationCheck = MethodOfA();

        if(operationCheck)
        {
            //do something to set the value of anotherReturnValue
        }

        return anotherReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Inherited Class:

```
public class B : A
{
    // Private variables here
    public B():base() { }

    public new bool MethodOfA()
    {
        return base.MethodOfA();
    }

    public new bool AnotherMethodOfA()
    {
        var testMock = new Mock<A>();

        //This is the part where I'm not sure how to get it to work.
        testMock.CallBase = true; // I have tried it with and without this statement. couldn't get it to work
        testMock.Protected()
                .Setup<bool>("MethodOfA")
                .Returns(true);

        return base.AnotherMethodOfA();
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
public class TestB
{
    private readonly B _sut

    //some Mocks here for setup

    public TestB()
    {
        _sut = new B();
    }


    [Fact]
    public void AnotherMethodOfA_Test()
    {
        var result = _sut.AnotherMethodOfA();
        Assert.True(result);
    }
}
```

What i need is basically, when I run my test from the TestB class, and it hits '_sut.AnotherMethodOfA()', within that method where it needs to call 'MethodOfA()', it should just use the value that I provide in the Mock and move on with the execution instead of calling the actual method (which it is doing now).

Now, if my Method-Under-Test were simpler and not call another method within it, this whole thing would have been simple (Which is the case in many of my other methods and I am testing those successfully already), but since this method calls another method during it's execution, i need to mock this intermediate method and pass that to my Method-under-test.

Comment: Are you sure its not failing because your setup is wrong? You are setting it to return false `.Returns(false);` whereas your test is asserting it to be `true`?

Comment: I just edited my question just so it's not confusing, but that return is not gonna affect the assert because that's not being tested.
MethodOfA is the mock, and that is supposed to return true (previouly false). That doesn't matter because based on that return value, the method being tested (AnotherMethodOfA()) does some operations and that is what is supposed to return true.

Answer (score 0):

This is good because you get to kill two birds with one stone: Reducing or eliminating inheritance, and employing dependency injection.

Instead of creating a `protected` method, imagine the thing that method does as an abstraction that your class depends on.

Instead of

```
protected bool AnotherMethodOfA()
```

Imagine

```
public interface IThingThatDoesSomethingAndReturnsABoolean
{
    bool MethodThatReturnsBool();
}
```

or

```
public delegate bool FunctionThatReturnsBool();
```

Then, rewrite the class `A` as follows:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly IThingThatDoesSomethingAndReturnsABoolean _thing;

    public A(IThingThatDoesSomethingAndReturnsABoolean thing)
    {
        _thing = thing;
    }

    protected bool AnotherMethodOfA()
    {
        bool anotherReturnValue = false;
        bool operationCheck = _thing.MethodThatReturnsBool();

        if (operationCheck)
        {
            //do something to set the value of anotherReturnValue
        }

        return anotherReturnValue;
    }
}
```

If you need to change the implementation of whatever it is that returns a `bool`, you don't have to do it by inheriting from `A`. That's a common pattern, but it tends to get tangled and create problems, including the exact one that you're asking about.

Instead, all you have to do is supply a different implementation of `IThingThatDoesSomethingAndReturnsABoolean`.

Now everything is testable. You can test `A` by providing a mock of the interface. You wanted the method that returns the `bool` to be testable, and now it is because it's no longer a `protected` method of some other class.

This is called preferring composition over inheritance. Instead of having classes work together by inheriting from each other, you write separate classes that do separate things and compose them to work together.

If your dependency class needs values "owned" by `A` which it previously accessed as properties or fields, you can make them arguments of the method. This makes it easy to see exactly how much information the method needs from `A`.

There are cases where inheritance makes sense, but separating functionality into dependencies instead of building them into an inheritance hierarchy is a good practice that will make your code testable and prevent other headaches that would likely come later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm sorry for the delay in replying but I went with a completely different route with this because going down this path (my original approach, not what you suggested) was going to cause other issues in a separate part of the code base.